# .NET Core How to get url from file path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my application structure

- DS.UI
- DS.Controllers
- DS.Repository

In App.Repositories, I have a folder where I store uploaded files. So far I am able to get the file location that is formatted like this:

> C:\Users\userone\source\repos\DBN\DS\DS.Repository\Repositories\Sample\acc_bcc.PNG

However when I try to open it via hyperlink like this, it won't open up

```
var url =  data.Link;
return "<a href='" + url + "'>" + data.Name+"</i></a>"
```

a href currently shows https://localhost:8080/C:\Users

How can I transform that into a usable for my a href?

EDIT:

Using the provided answer but I'm still stuck

```
"data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
    var url = "@Url.Action("GetFileData", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())/" + data.Link;
    return "<a href='" + url + "'>" + data.Name+"</i></a>"
}, "name": "Name"

public FileResult GetFileData(string Input)
{
    var path = @Input;
    var FileName = "abc";
    var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, FileName);
}
```

Comment: If the app root folder is `DS.Repository` then the url would become `/Repositories/Sample/acc_bcc.PNG`

Comment: This implementation is not good. The folder you store upload files should be a folder in web application.

Comment: If you really want to store in folder `C:\...`, you should read the content of file to binary and return as a FileResult

Comment: @VDWWD doesn't work when I try it. shows a 404 error.

Comment: @KhaiNguyen This is currently in development on my local laptop. When I upload it to the server there won't be a C:

Comment: The link should be like https://localhost:44325/Documents/Repositories/Sample/acc_bcc.PNG

This currently doesn't work. Removing Documents also doesn't work.

Comment: @JianYa You should replace the link by a file result, `http://localhost:5000/file/{fileid}`

Comment: @KhaiNguyen is there a sample? The documentation doesn't really show anything

Comment: Look into relative paths. My comment was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample that implement a file result that you can replace the url:

```
"data": function (data, type, row, meta) {
        var url = "@Url.Action("GetFileData", @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())?input=" + data.Link;
        return "<a href='" + url + "'>" + data.Name+"</a>"
    }, "name": "Name"

public FileResult GetFileData(string input)
{
    // input is a full path
    var FileName = "abc";
    var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(input);
    return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, FileName);
}
```

Comment: May I know what the @ sign is before the actual path?

Comment: This method is in FileController then url is `https://localhost:8080/File/GetFileData`

Comment: I've edited my question. i'm not sure which part of the file result I can use to give the url? This looks like it downloads the file

Comment: because you store file in Repository, user can only download it. Please look at my changes

Comment: But if I know the location and can download it can''t I generate a url from it?

Comment: I changed it to work off the Id instead. So I am able to download it right now. However I would like to actually open it up instead of downloading it.

Comment: If this is a image, you can try `<img>` not `<a>`

Comment: the image is just a sample, it can be a pdf also.

Comment: if it is a pdf, if browser installed pdf viewer, it will open pdf file. You can update the file name with correct extension.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost. So far it only downloads the file when the link is clicked on. I can't open it up in another tab.

Comment: Why should be `<a target="_blank">`